# Hot melt wood filler sticks for glue guns

Tags: holes, filler

I know I've used these before: Hard sticks for standard 7/16" diameter glue guns designed to fill holes so they can hold wood screws.  The advantage over other wood fillers is that (1) it can be pumped in hot at low viscosity to really fill up inaccessible voids, and then (2) it's ready to work as soon as it cools.

The sticks I used to use were so rigid at room temperature they would snap easily, but I haven't been able to find any hot melt sticks that don't bend quite a bit (which means they wouldn't be as good at holding a screw tight).

Does anyone know of materials like this?

Answer (score 4):

[This blog/ad](https://www.hotmelt.com/blogs/blog/knot-tec-knot-filling-wood-repair) mentions two wood filler products, one of which can be sanded/trimmed. It's outrageously expensive, but it was the only one I could find. Try adding "polyamide" to your search, as I believe that's the material glue-stick wood filler is usually made from. You might also be able to buy PUR (heat-activated polyurethane hot melt) intended for this purpose.